# Delphi XE5 Anonymous ShowModal doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am a newbie to Delphi XE5 and currently developing Android platform applications on my Windows desktop using Delphi XE5.
I have two forms(Form1 and Form2) and tried to show Form2 in modal way on Form1 according to the way showed in Marco's RAD Blog(http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/xe5_anonymous_showmodal_android.html).

But result was not as expected.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm2: TForm2;
begin
  frm2 := TForm2.Create(nil);

  ShowMessage('before frm2.ShowModal...');
  frm2.ShowModal (
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      if ModalResult = mrOK then
        if frm2.ListBox1.ItemIndex >= 0 then
          edit1.Text := frm2.ListBox1.Items [frm2.ListBox1.ItemIndex];
      frm2.DisposeOf;
    end
  );
  ShowMessage('after frm2.ShowModal...');
end;
```

I wrote above code and run the application on an Android device.
I clicked the Button1, then I got the messagebox "before frm2.ShowModal... ", next "after frm2.ShowModal...", and then Form2 was showed.

I expect that the order should be 1)"before frm2.ShowModal... " message, 2) Form2 being showed, and 3) "after frm2.ShowModal..." message.

What's wrong with me?

Comment: There is no real modality under android, just put the after showmodal comment at the end of your anonymous proc and use LU RD's freeing method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to the anonymous `ShowModal` is not blocking, which means that any code after the `ShowModal` will be executed first.

One note here. Calling `frm2.DisposeOf` is wrong. 
You must use this pattern:

declare

```
procedure TFrm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

See http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1585.
The documentation has been corrected in XE7, [Using FireMonkey Modal Dialog Boxes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_FireMonkey_Modal_Dialog_Boxes), but this pattern can be used in all Delphi versions.

---

**Conclusion**: if you want to execute code after the modal dialog is closed, put that code inside the anonymous method.

Comment: @whosrdaddy, directly calling DisposeOf in the anonymous method is wrong, since the anonymous frame relies on that object to be valid.

Comment: Ah it is the Modalresult setter that would give the problem, Ok deleting my comments :)

Comment: I moved the line `ShowMessage('after frm2.ShowModal...');` inside the anonymous method.
And I got the expected results. Thanks :-)